# Bijection and outer measure of two sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose I have two sets and they have the same cardinality which I believe means that there exists a bijection between them, kind of like an isomorphism but I don't know if I can call it that since all sets may not be groups.
Eg, let's consider the set $(0,1)$ and the set of irrationals between $(0,1)$, since they both have same cardinality, will they both have same outer measure ( which I know they have, but is this coincidence or actually due to bijection?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, two sets with the same cardinality do not need to have the same outer measure.  For example, all non-empty open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality, but intervals $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ have the same outer measure if and only if $b-a = d-c$.

Another important example is that the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, but has (outer) measure $0$.

In your specific example of $(0, 1)$ and $(0, 1) \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, these do have the same outer measure, but it isn't just because there is a bijection between them.

Comment: So if there is some form of isomorphism then is it possible? Like the actual problem i was working on was finding the measure of the set of all those numbers which contain 5 in their decimal expansion , and i thought about relating it somehow to this?

Comment: You could come up with a notion of "isomorphism" in this setting, but it will have to be something more than just "bijective function" (what you would want would be a measure-preserving bijection).  I'm not sure this really helps with the problem you're working on, though.

Comment: Thank you once again! One last query, is isomorphism measure preserving?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "isomorphism".  There isn't a single notion of "isomorphism", there are various notions depending on what kind of structure you're interested in; for example, if you are studying sets with no structure then by "isomorphism" you probably just mean "bijection", but if you are studying groups you probably care about group isomorphisms, in ring theory there are ring isomorphisms, in topology we call isomorphisms "homeomorphisms", and in measure theory the relevant notion of isomorphism is bijective measure-preserving transformation.

Comment: Oh ok..that clears up a lot of things! Thank you !